# AttributeError - class object has no attribute - Python Class

Tags: python, class

I have a class which is declared like:

```py
class K1:
  
    S_LENGTH = 1600
    SUFFIX = 0x06   

    def __init__(self,variant):
        self.__state_bytes_length = self.S_LENGTH
        self.__delimited_suffix = self.SUFFIX
        self.R_LENGTH = self.variant
        CAP_LENGTH = self.S_LENGTH - self.R_LENGTH
        self.H_LENGTH = CAP_LENGTH/2
        self.__rate_bytes_length = self.R_LENGTH
        self.__hash_bytes_length = self.H_LENGTH 

        self.__state_in_bytes = bytearray([0 for i in range(self.__state_bytes_length)])
        self.__capacity_bytes_length = self.__state_bytes_length - self.__rate_bytes_length
        self.__hash_bytes = bytearray()
```

I want to take an input value (called variant in my code) from the user and then assign that value to R_LENGTH. When I try to declare it in the aforementioned manner, it throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'K1' object has no attribute 'variant'
```

I am unable to figure out why this error occurs.

Comment: You haven't defined variant when you do `R_LENGTH = self.variant`.  Also indentation of those class variables look wrong.

Comment: I think you want `R_LENGTH = variant`, without the `self`. You may have a similar issue with `self.__SHA3_HASH_LENGTH` later, since that's not a defined attribute either. I'm not sure how to solve that one.

Comment: CAP_LENGTH is not defined.   So you need to post a [mre] instead of half working code.

Comment: It might help your troubleshooting to get rid of the `try` and `except` blocks you show in your calling code. If you let an exception bubble out uncaught, the interpreter will generally show you a traceback which identifies exactly where the error occurred. That's useful information, don't throw it away unless you have a good reason!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and (as already mentioned) create a [mre].

Comment: Kudos for updating the question.  Your code still generate syntax errors for the S_LENGTH and SUFFIX assignments.   In the line `CAP_LENGTH = S_LENGTH - R_LENGTH` is another syntax error, either use `K1.S_LENGTH` or `self.S_LENGTH` as you did earlier.  You need to post working code, otherwise you are just wasting our time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `AttributeError: 'K1' object has no attribute 'variant'` is due to the statement `R_LENGTH = self.variant` when `self.variant` has not been defined yet.  As @Blckknght said you probably want to use just `variant`.

I don't understand why are you are using class static data (`S_LENGTH`, `SUFFIX`).  In either case the posted code doesn't run as is as is so I used `0` as place holders:

```
class K1:
    S_LENGTH = 0
    SUFFIX = 0

    def __init__(self, variant):
        self.__state_bytes_length = self.S_LENGTH
        self.__delimited_suffix = self.SUFFIX
        self.__hash_bytes_length = (self.S_LENGTH - variant) / 2


k_obj = K1(42)
```